# Exception Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

hi guyz I'm new to spring JDBC I'm running first JDBCSpring application given in javaTpoint but I'm getting above error..please help me to solve this error.Iadded jdbc14.jar and all related jars also.

Answer (score 0):

The message says, that you have to add the oracle jdbc driver to your classpath.